# automatically filter an excel list

Tags: excel

I have an excel list and I would like to filter it automatically using a formula. I have a general list and need to create separate lists from it. 
So for example (as shown below), from the general list I want to create two tables (listed by A and B respectively). This would need to happen automatically. So when a new value is added to the general list, it would automatically be added to another list.

```
General list with the raw information
ID / value
A  / 13
A  / 2
B  / 32
A  / 1
B  / 40

List filtered by A values
ID / Value
A  / 13
A  / 2
A  / 1

List filtered by B values
ID / Value
B  / 32
B  / 40
```

Comment: I would be tempted to have a table and then pivottables based of this though you would want the refresh of the pivottables tied to a button. The pivottables would have the filters applied as appropriate.

Comment: It's bad data architecture to duplicate data. If you need to report on the list, build a report with the respective filters.